# Get data properly from an API with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am using an API which contains cards. And to call this API, I am using Axios.
So far so good, but I want to return the `deck_id` and for some reason it does not work. And I get the error "this.state.card.map is not a function"

Here is my current code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const CARD_API = "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/";

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       card: []
     }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
     const card= await axios.get(CARD_API)
     this.setState({ card})
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <ul>
           {this.state.card.map(card=>
              <li>{card.deck_id}</li>
           )}
        </ul>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: What format you are getting back the result from `axios.get(MOVIE_API)`? Most probably this means `movie` is not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `axios` you will get data inside `response.data` , so this is how you will get access to data

```
try {

    const response = await axios.get(MOVIE_API); //<-- This will have a lot more thing apart from data you need
    const movie = response.data; //<---- SOLUTION
    this.setState({ movie })

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```

> Note : Always put your `async await` code within `try catch` block if
>   possible

Comment: How do I call the `deck_id` to my return method?

Comment: @Alex, your code is good, just setState properly first as shown above, and make it array and not object, as you are looping through it in render part